# link_to destroy action not working for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, destroy

I'm trying to create a simple blog with rails 5.My app got a post,user,category and comment model.Everything is working fine except i cant get it to work the edit and destroy action for comments.

Here is the revelant controllers

comments_controller.rb

```
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @comment=Comment.new
    @post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
end

def create
    @post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment=Comment.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:body))
    @comment.user_id=current_user.id
    @comment.post_id=@post.id
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to(post_path(@post))
    else
        render('new')
    end
end


def edit
    @post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
end

def update

end

def destroy
    @post=Post.where(id: params[:post_id])
    @comment=Comment.where(post_id: params[:post_id],id: params[:id] )
    @comment.destroy(params[:post_id])
    redirect_to(post_path(@post))
end
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action(:post_find,only: [:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]) 
 before_action(:authenticate_user!,except: [:index,:show])
 before_action(:owner?,only: [:edit,:update,:destroy])
 before_action(:find_categories,only: [:new,:create,:edit,:update])
 def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @posts=Post.all
    else
        @category_id=Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @posts=Post.all.where(category_id: "#{@category_id}").order("created_at DESC")
    end
end

def new
    @post=Post.new
end

def create
    @post=Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id=current_user.id
    @post.category_id=params[:category_id]
    if @post.save
        redirect_to(root_path)
    else
        render('new')
    end
end

def show
end

def edit
end

def update
    @post.category_id=params[:category_id]
    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to(post_path(@post))
    else
        render('edit')
    end
end

def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to(posts_path)
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title,:body,:category,:category_id)
    end

    def post_find
        @post=Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def owner?
        if user_signed_in?
            if @post.user.id!=current_user.id
                redirect_to(root_path)
            end
        end
    end

    def find_categories
        @categories=Category.all.map{|c| [c.name,c.id]}
    end
end
```

posts/show.html.erb(the revelant part)

```
<h4>
Comments 
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    | <%= link_to("New comment",new_post_comment_path(@post)) %>
<% end %>
</h4>
<ul>
<% @post.comments.each do |f| %>
    <li> 
        <%= f.body %> | 
        by <%= f.user.email %> |
        <%= link_to("Delete",post_comment_path(f),method: :delete) %> 
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: what is the error and please post routes for comment and post as well

Comment: routes:Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for(:users)
 resources(:posts) do
  resources(:comments)
 end
 root(to: "posts#index")
end

Comment: getting a strange error:   Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=2 [WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ? AND "comments"."id" = ?]

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `comment_id` in place of `post_id` and you are not passing `post_id` in the **post_comment_path** link.

Try changing the `link_to` **Delete** action as below:

```
<%= link_to("Delete",post_comment_path(@post, f),method: :delete) %>
```

And, as you already have the comment to be destroyed, remove the `params[:post_id]` from destroy function as below:

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to(post_path(@post))
end
```

Read more about routing and URL helpers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

Comment: im getting wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) in the @comment.destroy line

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use [nested_scaffold gen](https://github.com/amatsuda/nested_scaffold) for another test app... from there you can get an idea for nested resources.